# Button style shows after page refresh on localhost - ReactJS / Material-UI / makeStyles/useStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am doing a ReactJS project and used Material-UI / makeStyle for styling.

The components work properly on live demo. But recently I have an issue with some of my components' styles on the localhost.

When I go from home to service page subheader looks with no style also pricing card buttons don't have any border and border-radius but when I refresh the page, it looks normal.

The button gets its border and bgcolor from main theme. Only padding and margin added as "btn" class.

```
 <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.btn}>
    {btnName}
  </Button>
```

To visualize it, I added the link.

Regards

[problem demo](https://share.getcloudapp.com/4guyjqkg)

Comment: sounds like you have some local issues. try to clear cache/work on-line/off-line, move to incognito/some other browser.

Comment: @Dekel  Does "to clear cache/work on-line/off-line" mean on chrome "cached images and files" part? if so, I did it and also moved to incognito and firefox besides chrome but no change.